# Не меняется тема Grub

Tags: grub, kali-linux, themes

Установил себе *Kali* вместе с *Windows 10*. Системы теперь грузятся через Grub. Ему выдалась тема от *Kali Linux* и я решил её поменять. Нашел [здесь](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1414997/) тему, скачиваю архив.

Далее там написано:

> Installation: 
> extract the themes / execute install.sh script included with it as super user ( sudo ./install.sh )

Выполняю скрипт, получаю сообщение о том, что он всё прошло успешно.

Далее запускаю `sudo update-grub` и вижу, что он всё равно грузит старую тему.

---

Пошёл по другому:

удалил то, что было установлено первым скриптом (там был ещё `uninstall.sh` скрипт)

Потом запускаю `grub-customizer`, выбираю архив с темой (заранее его перепаковал, что бы он содержал только файлы темы). Тема снова ставится успешно, никаких ошибок в консоли не вижу, но темы всё равно старая.

---

Ещё заметил, что *kali* тему он грузит с `/boot/grub/themes`, а кастомная тема ставится скриптом в `/usr/share/grub/themes` (`grub-customizer'om` ставится в `/boot/grub/themes`)

---

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

столкнулся с тем же. решил проблему так:

в терминале перешел в /etc/default/grub.d
открыл через nano  kali-themes.cfg
в GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub/themes/kali/theme.txt" изменил kali на bigsur (тема у меня такая). получилось:
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub/themes/bigsur/theme.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Помогли оба ответа, особенно команда обновления груба через консоль:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Grub почему то не обновляется из под программы Grubcustomaizer. После ввода команды

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

через консоль и перезагрузки помогло. Все установилось.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).