# Как удалить тему grub?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, themes

Установил на grub тему Fallout (У меня Ubuntu). Так как установка была с помощью install.sh. Мне понадобилось сейчас удалить тему, но как это сделать? Хочу вернуть всё к первоначальному виду.

Comment: В исходниках обычно есть скрипт удаления. Если не пробовали, то попробуйде её удалить с помощью apt.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1184329/178576

Comment: На будущее советую почитать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416